# Porque tengo el error "unexpected symbol" en la funcion cast?

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos en la que use reshape package.

Las variables son Date, Company Name, Price.
La hice data.frame y la llame Price.Per.Share

Mi programacion fue la siguiente:

```
md<-melt(Price.Per.Share,id=c("Company Name","Date"))   
a<-cast(md,Date~Company Name)
```

Y es en esta ultima linea en la que me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "a<-cast(md,Date~Company Name"

Ya verifique y no encuentro donde este el error, si bien lo que me devuelve R como error no tiene parentesis al final, yo si lo tengo en donde estoy programando

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió esta pregunta, por favor márcala como aceptada para que otros sepan cuál es la solución. Mira cómo otros pasamos por aquí dos años después :)

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenida Elvira. Por lo que veo el problema es que `Company Name` está separado por un espacio, entonces R considera que `Name` es algo aparte y no lo reconoce. La solución sería en el `melt` dar el nombre `Company_Name`, con un guión bajo en lugar del espacio. Alternativamente (y más complicado) podrías poner

```
`Company Name`
```

encerrado en acentos graves o backticks en la fórmula de `cast`. Ese es el modo de escapar espacios y que `R` evalúe `Company Name` todo junto. También así se escapan variables que comienzan con número o que tienen símbolos reservados. Lo ideal es no usar espacios en los nombres, siempre dan trabajo.

> Si el problema persiste sería necesaria una pregunta con un ejemplo completo para reproducir el error.

Comment: Si me funciono, pero ahora tengo otro problema.

Comment: En la salida que llame a, me sale un data.frame final pero solo de ceros y unos, no del valor que corresponde. Agradeceria tu ayuda :)

Comment: En ese caso te sugiero abrir otra pregunta en la que indiques el problema y se incluya el código necesario para reproducir el error/resultado no esperado. Sin los datos sería difícil saber que es lo que pasa. Si consideras que el problema de esta pregunta está resuelto podrías aceptar la respuesta, así queda marcada como aceptada para futuros y futuras visitantes.